# Vue.js mixin - access data from mixin method

Tags: vue.js

I have the following Vue mixin in which I want to be able to have some data members and set values for them inside of a mixin method:

```
export const adComponentMixin = {
    data() {
        return {
            ads1Code: "",
            ads2Code: "",
            ads3Code: "",
            adsMobileCode: "",
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.ads1Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-1")?.innerHTML ?? "";
        this.ads2Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-2")?.innerHTML ?? "";
        this.ads3Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-3")?.innerHTML ?? "";
        this.adsMobileCode =
            document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-mobile")?.innerHTML ?? "";
    },
};
```

However, when I try to access `this.ads1Code` inside of the method, I get this error:

```
Property 'ads1Code' does not exist on type '{ data(): { ad1Code: string; ad2Code: string; ad3Code: string; adMobileCode: string; }; mounted(): void; }'.
```

How do I manipulate data inside of the mixin from a mixin method?

Comment: in data function you define `ad1Code` and in mounted hook you call `this.ads1Code` , maybe `s` is missing

Comment: good on you for catching that; however, even fixing the typos, the issue doesn't go away. It has to do with something else

Comment: try using export default to this mixins or import in  { adComponentMixin  } in your component.

Answer (score -1):

to implement mixins in other components, you need to do as following :

File - adComponentMixin.js

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        ads1Code: "",
        ads2Code: "",
        ads3Code: "",
        adsMobileCode: "",
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.ads1Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-1")?.innerHTML ?? "";
    this.ads2Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-2")?.innerHTML ?? "";
    this.ads3Code = document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-3")?.innerHTML ?? "";
    this.adsMobileCode =
        document.getElementById("ads-div-hidden-mobile")?.innerHTML ?? "";
    }
```

}

File - some-component.vue

```
<template>
<div>example</div>
</template>
<script>
import adComponentMixin from './adComponentMixin';
export default{
    name:'some-component',
    mixins:[adComponentMixin ]
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking about. The error I get is in the mixin object, before I get to include it in a vue component.